# Using a 2D random walk numerical solution to solve an equation. Have the methodology but not the execution. Details in post

Tags: python, random-walk

Essentially, I am trying to solve the lapalcian using a random walk numerical solution. My domain is a circle, and the boundary condition is some function: f(phi) = cos(2phi). Essentially, I am trying to take a point within the 2D domain of my (unit) circle, randomly walk it until it meets the edge of the circle, so when x^2 + y+2 = 1. I am then going to take the x and y coordinate, find theta, then plug theta into my function to obtain a value. I will record and store this value, and repeat this process 'NumbRepeats' times. Then take the average of these values. This should give an approximate solution to the equation. I am not so concerned about the physics per se, I need help in what I have listed above the process I have described above. It may not necesarily be correct, but if I can get the program to do what I think is correct, then I will be happy. Thanks for the help. I will post my code below:

Note, my expertise is not coding, so apologies if this is difficult to understand. Any help is appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random


#Python code for 2D random walk
 
# defining the number of steps
n = 100000
 
#creating two array for containing x and y coordinate
#of size equals to the number of size and filled up with 0's
x = np.zeros(n)
y = np.zeros(n)

NumbRepeats = 100

PotBoundVec = []
for j in range(NumbRepeats):
    PotBound = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        val = random.randint(0, 1)
        if val == .25:
            x[i] = x[i - 1] + 1
            y[i] = y[i - 1]
        elif val == .5:
            x[i] = x[i - 1] - 1
            y[i] = y[i - 1]
        elif val == .75:
            x[i] = x[i - 1]
            y[i] = y[i - 1] + 1
        else:
            x[i] = x[i - 1]
            y[i] = y[i - 1] - 1

    if x[i]**2 + y[i]**2 == 1:
        Theta = np.tan(x[i]/y[i])
        PotBound = np.cos(2*Theta)
        PotBoundVec.append(PotBound)
        x = np.zeros(n)
        y = np.zeros(n)
    else:
        pass

print(PotBoundVec)
```

Comment: `random.randint(0, 1)` returns an integer.  It will never be equal to .25, .50, etc.

Comment: That makes sense. I changed it to random.random() and it still doesn't work, but at least that part is fixed.

Comment: It also might make more sense to use a while loop, as opposed to a for loop, in this case.

Comment: The result of `random.random()` has sixteen decimal places.  Practically speaking, it will _never_ be exactly equal to 0.25, 0.5, or 0.75.